# What does Liferay AutoLogin.login() API return?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

The interface of `AutoLogin.login()` needs to return a `String[]`  (see [here](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/security/auth/AutoLogin.html)).

What exactly should this array contain?

I saw some posts on StackOverflow where an array of 3 elements was returned: `user`, `password`, and a *boolean flag*. What is the intention of that boolean flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 arguments in credentials array

userId = the id of the user is logged
password = the user password
boolean = this is needed do know if the password is encrypted if true than it with be saved in session as it is  in the AutoLoginFilter

```
session.setAttribute("j_password", password);
```

else if it's false liferay encrypt the password before setting it to the session

Comment: Thanks Romeo. Is there any way we can enforce for not to validate the password but just user name.

Comment: You have to do an autologin hook and extending Baselogin